# Metricas de machine learning

Tags: r, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Eu gostaria de saber como avaliar qual modelo está melhor.
Por exemplo: estou aprendendo machine learning utilizando o dataset o titanic, e utilizei decisions tree, logistic regression e random forest, mas como posso avaliar qual terá o maior percentual de acertos??

li um material sobre metricas de avaliação de machine learning, mas nao entendi muito bem e menos ainda como utiliza.

de preferencia utilizando R

Comment: Pedro, este site recebe melhor perguntas sobre programação mais objetivas. A sua pergunta é muito aberta e uma boa resposta necessitaria um texto muito grande. Tente editar a sua pergunta explicando exatamente o que você não entendeu: "para que elas servem?", "qual é a ideia por trás?" Assim ficará mais fácil de conseguir uma resposta. A princípio o próprio "percentual de acertos" que você citou é uma métrica de avaliação. Tente também postar o código que você está usando para ajustar esses modelos que você mencionou.

Comment: Gostaria de saber como usar as metricas de avaliação

Comment: Algum lugar onde eu possa estudar o assunto, ja seria algo muito bom

Comment: Já tentou aqui: https://www.kaggle.com/amberthomas/titanic/predicting-survival-on-the-titanic

Comment: Neste [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/kernels) tem uma infinidade de scripts em R fazendo análises desse banco de dados.

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Como o colega @DanielFalbel já te explicou, a sua pergunta não está muito boa para o formato deste site (que não é um fórum - se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]). Vc diz que "leu material sobre métricas, mas não entendeu". Não entendeu o que? Procure explicar a sua dúvida!

Comment: @DanielFalbel, obrigado pelo link, ja me abriu um novo horizonte